# Error message in Bubble sort code in R language

Tags: r, bubble-sort

I did some programming work on R language to do the bubble sort. Sometimes it works perfectly without any error message, but sometimes, it shows "Error in if (x[i] > x[i + 1]) { : argument is of length zero". Can any one help me check whats wrong with it? I have attached my code below

```
example <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  repeat {
    hasChanged <- FALSE
    n <- n - 1 
    for(i in 1:n) {
      if ( x[i] > x[i+1] ) {
        temp <- x[i]
        x[i] <- x[i+1]
        x[i+1] <- temp
        hasChanged <- TRUE
        cat("The current  Vector is", x ,"\n")
      }
    }
    if ( !hasChanged ) break;
  }
}

x <-sample(1:10,5)
cat("The original Vector is", x ,"\n")
example(x)
```

Comment: Have you considered using `traceback` to determine which function call was getting the incorrect input? YOU SHOULD ALSO GET RID OF THOSE USELESS EMPTY LINES.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because you are iteratively decreasing `n`. Depending on the original vector's order (or lack thereof), `n` can reach the value of 1 after the last change. In that case, a further reduction of `n` in the next iteration step addresses the value `x[0]`, which is undefined.

With a minimal correction your code will work properly, without giving error messages. Try to replace the line

```
if ( !hasChanged ) break;
```

with

```
if ( !hasChanged | n==1 ) break
```

Basically you have two termination criteria: Either nothing has been changed in the previous iteration or `n` is equal to one. In both cases, a further iteration won't change the vector since it is already ordered.

By the way, in R programming you don't need a semicolon at the end of a command. It is tolerated/ignored by the interpreter, but it clutters the code and is not considered good programming style.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 though it’s worth nothing that the minimal change, while fixing the code, isn’t the best way of fixing this. A better way is decreasing the `n` at a later point; but this requires more substantial rewrite.